# Implement Page Object model in Cucumber

Tags: cucumber

How to implement page object model in Cucumber[ruby platform]. 
I have tried page object gem,but was able to implement it as expected. 
I am looking for something similar which we have in Selenium the Lazy initialization of web-elements and writing specific methods in selenium.

Comment: Cucumber has nothing to do with websites - so use Selenium inside Cucumber (or whatever webdriver implementation you want, and use page object as usual...)

Comment: mylenereiners is right, you can use the selenium driver in Cucumber if that's what you want to do.  What couldn't you set up with the page object gem?